# rename command is not overwriting as it should by default, how do I force overwrite?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, rename, mv

I have a bash script that uses the rename command as follows:

```
sudo rename 's/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/Date-$1-$2-$3__Time-$4:$5:$6/' 2019*
```

According to the rename man page the command should overwrite by default and not overwrite by using the -o flag. But when I run the script it is not overwriting existing files. However I get an error thrown back and the duplicate files do not get any other processing done by the script.

> Renaming Files
>
> 20190710220231.WAV not renamed: Date-2019-07-10__Time-22:02:31.WAV already exists
> 20190710220300.WAV not renamed: Date-2019-07-10__Time-22:03:00.WAV already exists
> 20190710220338.WAV not renamed: Date-2019-07-10__Time-22:03:38.WAV already exists
> 20190710220349.WAV not renamed: Date-2019-07-10__Time-22:03:49.WAV already exists

Frustrated, I tried to just use the mv command but gives me a different error:

> mv: target '20190710222433.WAV' is not a directory

So I added a / and get the same error. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the option `-f` to force over write existing files:

```
rename -f ...
```

man rename:

```
-f, --force
               Over write: allow existing files to be over-written.
```

Comment: Thank you UtLox. I know the question was voted down because if I would have read further blah blah... but when their is a flag to not overwrite, then common sense would indicate in a boolean world the default program would be the opposite. Either true or false - not true true false.